# How can I detect if there is a source tag inside the video tag

Tags: javascript

when I load a video I have this video tag:

```
<video data-required="video" id="video-upload-preview" controls="">
    <source src="blob:https://localhost:4000/cbbd8fac-6a37-4294-a86c-f32cedb6fb79">
</video>
```

When I haven't loaded a video the video tag is like:

```
<video data-required="video" id="video-upload-preview" controls=""></video>
```

How can I detect if there is a `source` tag inside the video or not using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const source = document.querySelector('video source')
 if(source){
    console.log(source)
 }
```